# How to achieve Aws MSK cost optimization

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-msk, cost-management

Hi i am deployed Amazon managed Kafka in AWS,

1. 3 Brokers
2. 50 gb size
3. t3 small instance

I want this MSK running 9 to 5 and scale down after that to save cost. Is there any mechanism to achieve this.

Its costing me 110$ every month, is there a way to reduce this, in the sense i am not using my application during the off hours, so in that time running msk is a cost overhead, i am searching for a way to reduce this.

Completely new to AWS, any help would be appreciated